# Drupal 8 with ReactJS as Frontend (Server Side Rendering)

Tags: php, reactjs, drupal-8

I am using Drupal 8 and ReactJS as frontend.

My first question is how do we do ReactJS(server side rendering) in Drupal 8 custom module? Because I have a custom module and I am just creating a block there and import the bundled javascript in my .libraries.yml. It is working but my problem now is SEO because my module is created using ReactJS.

My second question is how do we manage routing of ReactJS if it is inside of Drupal 8 project? I searched some projects but they separated the ReactJS project and Drupal 8 project, so I think they are using NodeJS or NextJS for their SSR for ReactJS but the Drupal 8 is not with ReactJS. What I am doing is I have routes inside of my ReactJS in my custom module. It is working but if you directly go some page like /sample and it doesn't exist in Drupal 8 routes it will show and error message like "Page not found" in Drupal 8 but the components inside ReactJS will still be rendered.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render reactjs on server(SSR) with PHP, you can research V8JS (quite difficult)
T think you should use reactjs(NEXT.js, React Universal, ...) to do frontend and cms or framework to do API for reactjs (like Laravel, CakePHP, Slim, etc...).If you want use Drupal and reactjs SSR, i think so difficult :D

Comment: So what you are suggesting is to separate my ReactJS and my Drupal 8?
Like I will deploy to another server my ReactJS and another server my Drupal 8?

Comment: Yes, this is the 'headless' approach. Your Drupal installation will be for focusing on what Drupal does well - manage content. Your React installation will focus on what React does well - build the UI - and render the data provided to you via your Drupal API's.